# How a machine learning model ( or its feature coefficients ) can be used to interpret if that features are relevant for a particular class?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, feature-selection

I am having a dataset with features like education, experience, month of joining etc, and my prediction is whether a person accepts an offer or not. I have created some model used sk-learn SVM, Randomforest etc. My objective is to understand, what are the features which play crucial role in determining whether the person has joined or not. I consider it as a classification problem.

After created the model, I obtain model.coeffc_ ( as in sklearn ), which gives values about the coefficients for each feature.
Suppose, i got 0.0028 for the month December, how could I interpret that this month has an influence on whether a person has joined or not. It may influence, the person to join , more than rejecting. A possibility is there, right? So, how these coefficient values for each feature can determine, the class ( especially which class )?

In regression, we can say that 0.028 value for December has an influence on growing the values, and -0.028 has influence on reducing the values. But how, this idea can be used for classification ? Please give some valuable insight.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is not directly related to programming, but to pure Machine Learning. Please consider moving it to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KeillЯandor - Will do that . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no big difference here between regression and classification. Positive values will always correlate with growing chance of classifying as positive class, and negative ones with chance becoming negative samples (I assume that **all your features are positive, otherwise you loose any meaning in that sense**). Be careful though, in both classification and regression **it is not true** that if one weight is bigger than the other then one feature is **more important**. There are many aspects which alter this behavior, in particular features values scale, variance, generaly - features values distribution.

In short. If your features are positive values, then **sign** of the feature shows towards which class thich feature is more correlated. The general classification procedure in linear models (such as linear SVM, not RF) is

```
cl(x) = sign( SUM_i coef_i x_i )
```

So you can see that if `x_i` are positive then the sign of `coef_i` either rises (for positive ones) or lowers (for negative) chance of `cl(x) = 1`. However if you have for example `coef_1 = 1` and `coef_2=180` it does not mean that second feature is more important, it might be the result of the fact, that second feature values are simply smaller, for example feature 1 might be a person height in cm (so for example 180cm) while the other feature is binary (0 or 1) so

```
x_1 * coef_1 = 180 * 1 = 180 = 1 * 180 = x_2 * coef_2
```

The actual importance of each feature is a whole field of study in machine learning community called "feature importance" or "feature selection methods". There are dozens of such approaches, and none of them is simply "the best".

Comment: Nice explanation. Most of the features are "yes" or "no". So, 1 or 0. Some are continous. So, after I got the model accuracy, precision and recall, how could I interpret that, which features were more relevant to make a new data to go to a particular class ?

Comment: as I said - there is no answer to such question, there are numerous approaches to answer it, google the "feature importance", which is a broad topic in ml. If your features are **conditionaly independent** and all are 0 and 1, then the absolute value is a clear indicator; however in general features are **never** conditionaly independent, and so this is far from being a simple question